# Exception right off the bat

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to run the FragmentLayout sample program using android:minSdkVersion="15"

It crashed right off the bet doing SetContentView(), getting below exception:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.examples.HelloFragmentLayout/net.examples.HelloFragmentLayout.FragmentLayout}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class Fragment
```

The "`net.examples.HelloFragmentLayout/net.examples.HelloFragmentLayout.FragmentLayout`" looks like a repeat but I don't know what caused this.

In my `fragment_layout.xml` (below), I am getting a warning "This `FrameLayout` can be replaced with a merge tag". Not sure if this has an impact.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Fragment class="net.examples.HelloFragmentLayout.TitlesFragment"
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Lowercase 'f' is needed in the layout.

`<fragment>` is a special tag interpreted by the `Activity` rather than being instantiated as a normal class (e.g., `LinearLayout`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment class="net.examples.HelloFragmentLayout.TitlesFragment"
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Jake.
I am getting:
net.examples.HelloFragmentLayout.TitlesFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
…when my fragment_layout.xml has this:
    <fragment class="net.examples.HelloFragmentLayout.TitlesFragment"…

Comment: Sounds like you are inheriting from `android.app.Fragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.