# Action Bar Sherlock + Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exception right off the bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042493/exception-right-off-the-bat)

I'm trying to use a dashboard fragment on my main page after installing Action Bar Sherlock.  I'm getting the error:

"Error inflating class fragment"

I've installed Action Bar Sherlock as a library project.  Here is the XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Fragment 
    class="myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android.fragments.DashboardFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

aMainMenu.java

```
package myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android.ui;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;

import myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android.R;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class aMainMenu extends FragmentActivity{
```

DashboardFragment.java:

```
    package myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android.fragments;

    import myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android.R;
    import myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android.ui.aNutritionLookup;
    import myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android.ui.aPlaces;
    import myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android.ui.aVitalAdd;
    import myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android.ui.aVitalsMy;
    import myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android.utils.AnalyticsUtils;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;


    public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

    public void fireTrackerEvent(String label) {
        AnalyticsUtils.getInstance(getActivity()).trackEvent("Home Screen Dashboard", "Click", label, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container);

        // MY VITALS *CLICK*
        root.findViewById(R.id.btnVitalsMy).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fireTrackerEvent("VitalsMy");
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), aVitalsMy.class));
            }
        });

        // ADD VITAL *CLICK*
        root.findViewById(R.id.btnVitalAdd).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fireTrackerEvent("VitalAdd");
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), aVitalAdd.class));
            }
        });

        // NUTRITION *CLICK*
        root.findViewById(R.id.btnNutrition).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fireTrackerEvent("NutritionLookup");
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), aNutritionLookup.class));                
            }
        });

        // PLACES *CLICK*
        root.findViewById(R.id.btnPlaces).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fireTrackerEvent("Places");
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), aPlaces.class));                
            }
        });

        // TWITTER *CLICK*
        root.findViewById(R.id.btnTwitter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fireTrackerEvent("Twitter");
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://twitter.com/#!/WellnessCheck")));                
            }
        });

        // Facebook *CLICK*
        root.findViewById(R.id.btnFacebook).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fireTrackerEvent("Facebook");
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/myvhc")));                
            }
        });



        return root;
    }
}
```

here is the logcat:

```
02-01 08:53:01.014: W/dalvikvm(8023): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020950)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android/myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android.ui.aMainMenu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class Fragment
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class Fragment
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.setContentView(FragmentActivity.java:421)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android.ui.aMainMenu.onCreate(aMainMenu.java:32)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     ... 11 more
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android-1.apk]
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
02-01 08:53:01.114: E/AndroidRuntime(8023):     ... 19 more
```

Comment: Can you include the code for DashboardFragment rather than aMainMenu? Also check out this link for Java naming conventions of classes/packages - http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Comment: Solution: use lowercase 'f' (i.e., `<fragment ..` NOT `<Fragment ...`)

Comment: OK, the lowercase 'f' did work after all, it didn't work at first, strange. Thanks Jake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jake Wharton's solution described in his comment worked:

> Solution: use lowercase '`f`' (i.e., `<fragment` .. NOT `<Fragment` ...)

So I changed `<Fragment>` to `<fragment>`.